# Selecting values from a combobox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes.

```
<select name="ticketType">
        <option selected>Ticket type</option>
        <option value="55">Promo pass</option>
        <option value="65">Regular pass</option>
      </select>
      <select name="campingNumber">
        <option selected>Camping spots</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="30">1</option>
        <option value="50">2</option>
        <option value="70">3</option>
        <option value="90">4</option>
        <option value="110">5</option>
        <option value="130">6</option>
      </select>
      <p>Price: € <span id="price"></span></p>
```

What I want to do is to take the values from both and add them together, everything works, but if I select another value from combobox it's keep adding together to the total.
This is my jquery:

```
var price=0;
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select[name=ticketType]').change(
      function(){
        price =price +  parseInt($(this).val());
        $('#price').text(price);
      }
      );
  }
   );
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select[name=campingNumber]').change(
      function(){
        price =price +  parseInt($(this).val());
        $('#price').text(price);
      }
      );
  }
  );
```

And this values I want to be updated to database, for ticket everything works ok, but for camping number, the value is the price of camping spot, and the numbers from 0-6 are for how many people you buy a camping spot, how can I add this to the table in database?
For the database I have following table:

```
person_nb (int 10)
price (int 10)
```

So value from camping number I want to be added to price, and in person_nb I want the value between the  for campingNumber combobox.

```
$query2 = $conn-> prepare("INSERT INTO user_acc (email, ticket_price) VALUES (:email2, :ticket);"); 
$query2->bindParam(':email2', $email);' '$query2->bindParam(':ticket', $ticketType);
$query3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation (price, person_nb) VALUES (:price, :personNumber);"); 
$query3-> bindParam(':price', $campingPrice); 
$query3-> bindParam(':personNumber', $totalNumberOfPersons);
```

So this are the queries, but for totalNumberOfPersons I don't know how to get a value. For example '1' the price is 30, and the number of persons should be 1.

Comment: I believe you need to use AJAX to insert data in database

Comment: I update the database using query's from register.php, everything is updated when a user is registering, so the user info is updated, the ticket price also, but for camping only the price is updated, if he select more than one camping spots I don't know how to put this in database, and with AJAX is a little bit hard cause yet I don't have too much knowledge about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep adding to the total without resetting any values so try this:

```
 var price=0;
 var pricex = 0;
 var pricey = 0;
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('select[name=ticketType]').change(
          function(){
            pricex = parseInt($(this).val());
            price = pricex + pricey;
            $('#price').text(price);
          }
          );
      }
       );
    $(document).ready(
      function() {
        $('select[name=campingNumber]').change(
          function(){
            pricey = parseInt($(this).val());
            price = pricex + pricey;
            $('#price').text(price);
          }
          );
      }
      );
```

Comment: It's working, thank you, any ideas how to update the table for camping? The price will be updated with the value from the selected option, but I don't know how to update for how many persons is a camping spot.

Comment: I'm going to need to see your back end code for that @Alexandru , and the code you are using to post to your back end

Comment: @Alexandru can you edit your question with this code? it's a pain to look at the code like this

Comment: `$query2 = $conn-> prepare("INSERT INTO user_acc (email, ticket_price) VALUES (:email2, :ticket);");`
`$query2->bindParam(':email2', $email);`
`$query2->bindParam(':ticket', $ticketType);`
`$query3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation (price, person_nb) VALUES (:price, :personNumber);");`
`$query3-> bindParam(':price', $campingPrice);`
`$query3-> bindParam(':personNumber', $totalNumberOfPersons);`
 So this are the queries, but for totalNumberOfPersons I don't know how to get a value. For example `<option value="30">1</option>` the price is 30, and the number of persons should be 1.

Comment: @Alexandru can't you just do $totalPrice = $campingPrice * $totalnumberofpersons? I don't know what your tables look like so I don't really know what you mean

Comment: I will try with hard coded, if will not gonna work probably I will put another question with database tables and everything. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Alexandru if you post the new question post the link here, i'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var price;
$(document).ready(
 function() {
 $('select[name=ticketType]').change(
  function(){
   price=0;
    price =price +  parseInt($(this).val()) +  parseInt($('[name="campingNumber"]').val());
    $('#price').text(price);
  }
  );
  }
  );
 $(document).ready(
  function() {
   $('select[name=campingNumber]').change(
    function(){
      price=0;
    price =price +  parseInt($(this).val()) +  parseInt($('[name="ticketType"]').val());
    $('#price').text(price);
   }
   );
}
);
```

Comment: what you are expecting? when ever you are selecting the value, the price need to be changed? price is a single value or need two different totals of these two combo boxes?

Comment: To add the values together, value from ticketPrice and campingNumber, this is the total price that needs to be 'paid' after registering. I said paid because this is my 1st year ending project, so for the moment only the registration should work. This one I fixed with the @Jeremy C. code, but still having issues how to update the database for person_nb, because I don't know how to get the value regarding numbers of person, because value what I used in combobox it's the price for the camping and ticket.